# "Rotating" tables in Lua?

Tags: lua

Let's say that I have table X:

```
{
  {1,1,1},
  {1,0,0},
  {1,1,1}
}
```

My goal is to "rotate" X, so that it turns into table Y:

```
{
  {1,1,1},
  {1,0,1},
  {1,0,1}
}
```

I would also prefer if the solution also works for asymmetrical tables, like Z:

```
{
  {1,1,1},
  {1,0,0},
  {1,1,1},
  {1,1,0}
}
```

Please make this work with Vanilla Lua 5.1, no additions.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community. Although this post is clear, concise and precise, it isn't quite what this site is for. We're here to help; not to do. Please explore more of the site and the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: This operation is called transposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function transpose(m)
   local rotated = {}
   for c, m_1_c in ipairs(m[1]) do
      local col = {m_1_c}
      for r = 2, #m do
         col[r] = m[r][c]
      end
      table.insert(rotated, col)
   end
   return rotated
end

function rotate_CCW_90(m)
   local rotated = {}
   for c, m_1_c in ipairs(m[1]) do
      local col = {m_1_c}
      for r = 2, #m do
         col[r] = m[r][c]
      end
      table.insert(rotated, 1, col)
   end
   return rotated
end

function rotate_180(m)
   return rotate_CCW_90(rotate_CCW_90(m))
end

function rotate_CW_90(m)
   return rotate_CCW_90(rotate_CCW_90(rotate_CCW_90(m)))
end
```

Example of usage:

```
local m1 = {
  {1,1,1},
  {1,0,0},
  {1,1,1},
  {1,1,0}
}

local m2 = rotate_CCW_90(m1)
-- m2 now is {
--    {1, 0, 1, 0},
--    {1, 0, 1, 1},
--    {1, 1, 1, 1}
-- }

local m3 = transpose(m1)
-- m3 now is {
--    {1, 1, 1, 1},
--    {1, 0, 1, 1},
--    {1, 0, 1, 0}
-- }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want transponieren:

```
function transponieren (udata)
    local tdata = {}
    for y, xs in pairs (udata) do
        for x, value in pairs (xs) do
            tdata[x]=tdata[x]or{}
            tdata[x][y]=value
        end
    end
    return tdata
end

local udata = {
    {  1,   0, 0.9},
    {0.9, 0.5,   1},
    {  0, 0.1,   1},
}
udata = transponieren (udata) -- transponiered
```