# Rotate 3D Grid Lua

Tags: lua, rotation, transform

***Hi!***

I was wondering how I would go about to rotate a 3D grid 90 degrees, or rather a 2D grid one layer at a time.

Layer 1 example:

```
X O X X X                X X O X X
X X X X X                X X O X O
O O X O O ==90° Right==> X X X X X
X X X X X                X X O X X
X X X X X                X X O X X
```

It would be nice if this worked in both directions so I don't have to reiterate  it three more times just to rotate it to the left.

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46492960/1847592) of implementation of 2D-matrix rotation

Answer (score 1):

Don’t restructure your data - that could be very costly, especially if the grid size is very large. Instead, use different iteration logic to traverse the grid. For example:

With the above data, keep it as shown on the left:

```
rows = {}
rows[1] = {“X”, “O”, “X”, “X”, “X”}
rows[2] = {“X”, “X”, “X”, “X”, “X”}
rows[3] = {“O”, “O”, “X”, “O”, “O”}
rows[4] = {“X”, “X”, “X”, “X”, “X”}
rows[5] = {“X”, “X”, “X”, “X”, “X”}
```

Iteration method 1 would be:

```
for i = 1, #rows do
    for j = 1, #rows[i] do
        — Do something with rows[i][j]
    end
end
```

That would read the data like the grid on the left: across the rows, top to bottom.

Iteration method 2 would be:

```
for i = 1, #rows[1] do
    for j = #rows, 1, -1 do
        — Do something with rows[j][i]
    end
end
```

That would read the data on the left *as if it were* the grid on the right.

Now, it you actually need to rearrange the data (because its getting written out to an image file, for example), then use the above nested loops to traverse the grids and write out the cell values with each iteration.

Also: if your grids are always size 5x5, then you can simplify the above code. You can hard-code the loops to go from 1 to 5 instead of using the # length operator.